# How to implement only single cell selection in each section in the tableview in iOS, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, sections

I have a table view with 5 sections and I have set the tableview selection to multiple. Each section have different number of rows. What I want is to set that the user can select only one cell from each section(in my table user can select any number of cells).
ex: 5 cells from 5 sections.

It should be impossible to select more than one cell from any section. If user select another cell from same section, previously selected cell should be deselected. How can I do this. This is a sample implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    HoteldetalcelloneTableViewCell *cellone = (HoteldetalcelloneTableViewCell *)[self.detailtableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    HoteldetailcelltwoTableViewCell *celltwo = (HoteldetailcelltwoTableViewCell *)[self.detailtableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //I have implement for two sections to test.
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {

       HotelDetailsone *secone = [roomonearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       HoteldetailsforBooking *book = [HoteldetailsforBooking new];
        if([secone.offerallow isEqualToString:@"True"])
        {
            celltwo.selectedsignLabel.hidden = NO;

        }
        else
        {

            cellone.selectedsignLabelone.hidden = NO;

        }
//        [self.detailtableView reloadData];
      NSLog(@"price for room 1 : %@", secone.itempriceText);

    }
    else
    {
        HotelDetailsone *sectwo = [roomtwoarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        HoteldetailsforBooking *book = [HoteldetailsforBooking new];
        if([sectwo.offerallow isEqualToString:@"True"])
        {
            celltwo.selectedsignLabel.hidden = NO;

        }
        else
        {

            cellone.selectedsignLabelone.hidden = NO;

        }
        //        [self.detailtableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"price for room 1 : %@", sectwo.itempriceText);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to allow only one selection from whole table or one selection per one section?

Comment: one selection per one section @Lion

Comment: How many custom cell do you have here?

Comment: You have 5 sections.So I think One Custom cell is enough for you.

Comment: i would suggest to make tableview multiselect and validate based on which section is selected. (i.e do not allow another selection in the same section)

Comment: have two custom cells @user3182143

Comment: @LeXeR yes, I want to do so. I'm asking how to do so.

Comment: Going down the multi-select route has a problem - the system calls `-didDeselect:` before it calls `-didSelect`. Which means that when the cell is being deselected, you don't know whether a) there even is a newly selected cell  or b) if it is in the same section

Comment: Check my update in answer!

Comment: bill actually what solution do you expect?

Comment: Do you want to tick the selected cell in each section?

Comment: no I want to select only once cell from one section. ex :`user should able to select any cell from section 1, any cell from section 2 , any cell from section 3`. any selection from one section should not affect to any other section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep track on the selection of cell. So you need to store selected `indexpath` in array.

in `ViewController.h` declare property like this

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *selectionData;
```

Now in `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectionData=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];


    if ([self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section] ] != nil) {

        NSMutableArray *sectionData=[[self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section]] mutableCopy];

        if (![sectionData containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.numberlabel.text = @"2";
        }
        else
        {
            cell.numberlabel.text = @"***";
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell.numberlabel.text = @"2";
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"selected section :%li ---> selected row :%li",(long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
    [self handleSelectionForSection:indexPath.section row:indexPath.row];
    [self.tablev reloadData];

}

-(void)handleSelectionForSection:(long)sectionIndex row:(long)rowIndex
{


    if ([self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex] ] != nil) {

        NSMutableArray *sectionData=[[self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]] mutableCopy];

        if (![sectionData containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]])
        {
            //removing previous selected rows
            [sectionData removeAllObjects];
            [sectionData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

            [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];
        }
        else
        {
            //cell you tapped is already selected,
            // you can deselect it by removing object

            //if you dont want to deselect it comment following lines
            [sectionData removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

            [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];
        }


    }
    else
    {
        //section key not available so we need to create it
        NSMutableArray *sectionData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [sectionData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

        [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];

    }

    NSLog(@"All Selection : %@",self.selectionData);

}
```

Your `numberOfRowsInSection`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `titleForHeaderInSection` will remain same.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: thanx to you, the selection is working fine.that means if I select from first section it does not affect to others.now the problem is, user can select more than from the same section.I upvoted this.

Comment: so you want to restrict user to select more than one cell in same section ?

Comment: yep.that is what I need

Comment: @bill updated answer. Updated method `handleSelectionForSection`. please check.

Comment: @Mahesh how can I deselect all rows in the next sections? e.g. if I selected row 2 in section 3, all selected rows in sections 4,5,6,... should be deselected.
any help? Thank

Comment: @Hatim in that case you have to remove all section data next to selected section from the `selectionData` dictionary. So if you select any row in 2nd section then remove all the section entries from `selectionData` > selected section index. Let me know if you do not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `selection` property of tableview from interface builder. Select your tableview in IB and then select `attribute inspector and set`single selection`to`selection` property like below screenshot.

[image]

Or you can set programattically,

```
 self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

**Update :**

If you want single selection per section then you can implement `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` as below,

```
 - (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
for ( NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ) {
    if ( selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section )
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO] ;
}
return indexPath ;
}
```

In this case you should allow multiple selection in `tableview` i think.

Reference : [Answer of John Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553323/xcode-tableview-how-to-select-one-row-in-each-section)

Comment: This answer correctly explains how to achieve single selection in tableviews. Unfortunately that isn't what the OP is asking about - they want to be able to select one row per section at any given time.

Comment: the reference answer is what the op wants.

Comment: @LeXeR : yeah, that's the original post wants!

Comment: this works fine if the row count is less then 5 for each section.if not ex :`if I select first row from first section it select, and fifth cell from the section 1 and same select from section 2 also.`

Comment: I am not getting what you have said in comment. What exactly happens?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are updating celltwo / cellone selectedsignLabel.hidden on table selection. so @Lion solution will not working. You have to save the last selected index using below code :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *selectedIndexPathDict;
// in viewDidLoad:   
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
self.selectedIndexPathDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//In table view delegate.
- (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    NSString *indexSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.section];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = self.selectedIndexPathDict[indexSection];
   if ( indexPath1) {
       HotelDetailsone *secone = [roomonearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       secone.offerallow ^= YES; //toggle bool value
      // update new selected index path.
      [self.selectedIndexPathDict setObject:indexPath forKey:indexSection];
     //reload previous selected cell.
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    });


  } else {
      //initialise selected index path
      self.selectedIndexPathDict[indexSection] = indexPath;
  }
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO] ;

   return indexPath ;
}
```

I have not update the complete working code. But this is the way to achieve. You can also use the userdefault instead of self.selectedIndexPathDict.